# Multidimensional Array - Get unique values, but count all duplicates

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, count, numbers

I have a multi-dimensional array that I would like to get unique sub-values from, but also have a count of how many times those unique sub-values occurred.

For instance, this would be my starting array:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1533438473619168
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3333333333333333
                )
        )
 [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1533438473619168
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5555555555555555
                )
        )
 [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1533438473619168
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 77777777777777777
                )
        )
```

In the end, I'd like to have an array that looks like this:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1533438473619168
                    [count] => 3
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3333333333333333
                    [count] => 1
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5555555555555555
                    [count] => 1
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 77777777777777777
                    [count] => 1
                )
        )
```

Is there any general/easy way to do this without iterating through the first array for each value, comparing/storing the values in a temporary array, checking them, and adding to the count?

Comment: No, there's no easier way than that.

Comment: use id as key for new array to avoid comparing/checking. Then you can remove it using `array_values`

Comment: for starters i would merge al your arrays together, then you only have to loop through one array.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help.  I ended up just doing it manually (wasn't hard, as I expected, but was more cumbersome than I had hoped).

Answer (score 1):

To get this exact format you may need to iterate thought your current array and do the counting manually, however php has the array_count_values() and array_unique()  functions for this kind of thing:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 1):

Because you are only concerned with the deepest values of the array, using `array_walk_recursive` seems suitable for this. Note that a reference to the output array `$counted` is used in the callback.

```
array_walk_recursive($ids, function($id, $k) use (&$counted) {
    $counted[$id] = isset($counted[$id]) ? $counted[$id] + 1 : 1;
});
```

Using the id as the key in the `$counted` array will simplify the counting. The result of this will be somewhat different from your suggested output, but in my opinion it would actually be simpler to use. (e.g. `foreach ($counted as $id => $count) {...`).

```
$counted = array(
    "1533438473619168" => 3
    "3333333333333333" => 1
    "5555555555555555" => 1
    "77777777777777777" => 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this to see if it's more efficient than my current solution but both seem to use a temporary array for storage and the same lines of code.